# how to delete record with codeigniter and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have working codeigniter controller and view which sucessfully delete record. I would like to do it with ajax - jquery, to avoid reloading the page, and sure enough I will need to prompt the user if he is sure about deleting the record.

Any code snippet would be deeply appreciated, since i don't know where to start:

Here is the code from the controller:

```
public function deleteUser()
    {
        $this->load->model('backOfficeUsersModel');
        $deleteWhat = array(
            'dpage' => $this->input->post('dpage'),
            'rid'   => $this->input->post('rid')
        );
        $this->backOfficeUsersModel->delete($deleteWhat['rid']);
        redirect($deleteWhat['dpage']);
    } // end of function deleteUser
```

Here is the view that I have now: (just the php code is presented for the sake of simplicity)

```
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
                            echo form_open('backOfficeUsers/deleteUser');
                            echo form_hidden('dpage', 'backOfficeUsers/displayAllUsers');
                            echo form_hidden('rid', $user['userid']);
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>";

                            $data = array(
                                'name' => 'row_sel',
                                'id' => $user['userid'],
                                'value' => $user['userid'],
                                'class' => 'select_row'
                            );

                            echo form_checkbox($data);

                            //echo "<input type='checkbox' class='select_row' name='row_sel'>"; 
                            echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $user['userid'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $user['firstname'] . " " . $user['lastname'] . "</td>  ";
                            echo "<td>" . $user['username'] . "</td>  ";
                            echo "<td><a href=mailto:" . $user['email'] . ">" . $user['email'] . "</td>  ";
                            echo "<td style='text-align: center;'>";
                            echo anchor("backOfficeUsers/displayEditUserForm/$user[userid]/", "<i class=splashy-pencil></i>", "class=ext_disabled");     
                            echo "</td>";
                            echo"<td style='text-align: center;'>";
                            $confirm = "class='splashy-remove' style='border:none; width:16px; height:16px;'";

                            echo form_submit('submit', '', $confirm);
                            echo"</td></tr>";

                            echo form_close();
                        }
```

Any help (code snippet, or link to some example) will be deeply appreciated

Regards,Zoran

Comment: Zoran, you need to start to +1 and accept answers that help you more often :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, go easy on the `echo` statements. If you find yourself using them *excessively* it probably **because you should be writing HTML with embedded PHP and not PHP with embedded HTML.** Also, when posting questions on SO, remove the extra fluff that only serves to confuse answerers. There is a lot of *crap* in your code that does not get to the *heart* of your problem.

### From scratch, here's the HTML scaffolding I'd use:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <? foreach($users as $uK => $uV):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $uV['username']?></td>
            <td><a class='deleteUser' href='backOfficeUsers/deleteUser/<?= $uV["id"]?>'>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>        
    <? endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

### Then the jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".deleteUser").click(function(e){
            $this  = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.get(url, function(r){
                if(r.success){
                    $this.closest("tr").remove();
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

### And the controller:

```
class Backofficeuser extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        ...
    }

    function deleteUser($id){
        $u = new User($id);
        if($u->delete()) return json_encode(array("success" => true));            
    }

}
```

I used Datamapper's syntax here for record deletion, please adapt to Active Record. The code is not tested, it was written here in the SO editor - but it is how I would go about things.

Comment: You provide excellent advice about echo statements. Thanks. I will now try to implement your solution.

Comment: Getting stuck on delete function in controller. Code there now looks like this:

Comment: public function deleteUser($userid)
        {
            
            $ids = $userid;
            $this->load->model('backOfficeUsersModel');
            $this->backOfficeUsersModel->delete($ids);
            return json_encode(array("success" => true));  
        } // end of function deleteUser

Comment: adding  $this->displayAllUsers(); on the end didn't help. page remain on blank controller function:that is, url looks like:     /backOfficeUsers/deleteUser/50

Comment: The page shouldn't change at all on an AJAX request. Are you sure you're calling `e.preventDefault();`? Use Chrome Dev tools to inspect the response (Network tab) from the server.

Comment: I don't know what `diplayAllUsers()` is, that's your own function... as is the `delete()` method, as far as I know. Post the code.